# Issue in seeing members in HSBN vNext Beta

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to use the IBM Blockchain service on Bluemix, but having issues in seeing members (and consequently cannot create the required channels).

My intended setup is Org1 and Org2 on ChannelA . Consequently added Member1(Org1) and Member2(Org2). Once the users agreed to join the network , the peers appear to have got created correctly(i.e. I  can see them on UI), but I can only see only one of the  members(Member2).

Could folks advise , what am I missing here ?

The same situation is true when I try to create my ChannelA(I can only see and add only Member1 ... though my need is to add both members to the channel).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some clarifications on the scenario might make it possible to better understand what is being observed.

Does the following sequence of steps match what was being tried?

1. An initial participant creates an instance of the Blockchain service and becomes the first member.
2. This initial member adds a peer.
3. Then the initial member sends an invitation to invite someone else to become the second member.
4. The invitation is accepted and then there are two members of the network.
5. The second member adds a peer.
6. Then a channel is created.  Both participants are selected when creating the channel.

In the above scenario, the channel should be able to be created with both members.  Is this the scenario that you were following?  If not, how were the sequence of steps different?

Where are you looking for members of the network?  If you select Resources > Members, the status of whether an invitation has been accepted will be displayed.  The channel creation dialog allows you to select a company and then add this company as a member of the channel.  The Channels > select a channel > Members  panel will show the participants in a channel.